# RestBuilder Plugin. How can I upload a file without creating a file?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Currently, I can upload files(exist) with Grails's RestBuilder.
However, I want to upload a file without creating a file .
I want to create binary data (= Text File) in a program and send it directly
Is it possible?

```
RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
RestResponse resp = rest.post(url){
    contentType("multipart/form-data")
        setProperty("dataFile",[filePath])// <- it can
        setProperty("dataFile",[ byte[] or inputStream() or String ? ])// <- Is it possible?
}

'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you figured this out already, but you can just use a String reference or a byte[] just as you can use File instances for the multipart request using RestBuilder. It should 'just work' e.g.

```groovy
RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
RestResponse response = rest.post(url) {
    contentType 'multipart/form-data'
    stringPart = 'hello' // String
    bytePart = '68656c6c6f'.decode64() // byte[]
    filePart = new File('/path/to/file.jpg') // File
}
```